# My answer did not solve OPs problem; now what

Tags: discussion

I tried to answer [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/597941/active-directory-integrated-dns-records-deletion-by-system/597949), since I had similar problems earlier and managed to solve them. However, it appears that the fix that worked for me does not work for the OP and I have no idea what the problem is. I do not feel like I am able to solve the OPs problem, but my answer is still sitting there.

What is the honourable thing to do here? Should I remove my answer, since it does not solve the problem? Should I edit it to reflect that, although this answer may fix similar problems, it does not fix the OPs problem specifically?

Comment: This happened to me too and in the end I've left the [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/178470/4276) because some people found it useful. Though I mentioned that it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's entirely up to you what you want to do with your answer. You provided it in good faith based on the information in the question at the time you wrote it.

Remember - we're here not just for the OP but for everyone else who my be experiencing similar problems. Your answer will be useful to some people.

There is no honour where rep is concerned.

Comment: This is also why we tend to be heavyhanded when people submit "dangerous" answers without disclosures, even if an answer has already been accepted. Inexperienced people are going to cruise into that Q&A and come away with "solutions" that are a danger to themselves and others.

Comment: Oh yes, that's what voting and editing is for.

Comment: +1 for the "no honour where rep is concerned" part